# Append search results to respective parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

I'm implementing autocomplete using webSocket. When I type in the input field which has the classname `item-search-results`, a bunch of result will show up [search results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyvrL.png). My problem is the result will is only attach to the very first `item-search-results` input field.

But I need the results show up under the right `item-search-results` input field. 
For example, I type on the 4th `item-search-results` input field, but the results are attach to the first one [results are attach to the first row screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nijUR.png)

Here is my webSocket js, I use jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  let webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/autocomplete");
  webSocket.onopen = (msgEvent) => {
    console.log('connected to WebSocket!');
  };

  webSocket.onmessage = (msgEvent) => {
    /* results shows {"results":{"results":[{..}]}}.
    results.results shows {results:[{..}]}
    results.results.results shows [{...}], which is an array */
    let results = JSON.parse(msgEvent.data),
        resultsArr = results.results.results;
    console.log(resultsArr);
    $.each(resultsArr, (index, value) => {
      $('<div>' + value['name'] + '</div>').attr('id', 'item-search-results-' + index).appendTo($('.item-search-results'));
    });
  };

  webSocket.onclose = (msgEvent) => {
    console.log('disconnected');
  };

  webSocket.onerror = (msgEvent) => {
    console.log('there\'s an error');
  };

  /**
  *  Request to display data
  */
    $('.add-items-table').on('input', '.item-input', (e) => {
      let value = e.target.value;
      webSocket.send(value);
      console.log(value);
    })
})
```

Comment: I gess this may help: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Do you have to use jquery to do that? It would be much easier using some front-end framework like vue or react.

Comment: I tried the closest but nothing happened, the results won't even show up. :(

Comment: I can't use any framework for this project @Guzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websockets are irrelevant here, and I don't understand why you are doing an append inside loop. When trying to do something like this, you need to use the `$(this)` selector which will be the element you actually click.

At the top of your script create a global variable or namespace.

```
var Item = {};

/* In this chunk of code, create an object which you can use as a reference */
$('.add-items-table').on('input', '.item-input', (e) => {

   /* this will be the correct .item-search-results div */
   var Item.list = $(this).siblings('.item-search-results');

   let value = e.target.value;
   webSocket.send(value);
   console.log(value);
})
```

Finally, append to the correct `<div>`.

```
.appendTo(Item.list);
```

Comment: why use `var` Item.list? What's the differencet? I'm quite confuse (in general) because I was taught always use `const` and `let`

Comment: I'm not familiar with let, if that's how you are declaring your variables use that then.

Comment: I got an error.
`websocket_orders.js:44 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`
`let Item = {};
    $('.add-items-table').on('input', '.item-input', (e) => {
      let Item.list = $(this).siblings('.item-search-results');
      let value = e.target.value;
      webSocket.send(value);
      console.log(value);
    });`

Comment: Ok, the problem is that you're mixing javascript and jQuery. In this case you need to use `var`.

Comment: There shouldn't be any syntax errors in what I posted.

Comment: So what I did was to declare a variable `let activeInput;` and then in the eventlistener function, `activeInput = e.target;` and then in the append function, it's `itemSearchResults.appendTo($(activeInput).closest('.item-search-container'));`. So the result lists attach to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `Websocket` But here is how you will approach.Get last `Row` of table and append data after that particular row.

```js
var placeHolder=` <tr>
                <td style="width: 16.66%">
                  <input type="text" name="quanty" value="">
                </td>
                <td class="item-search-container">
                  <input class="item-input" id="item-input-0" type="search" name="item" value="">
                  <div class="item-search-results"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="quanty" value="">
                </td>
                
              </tr>`;
function addItem(){
   let totalElem=document.getElementsByClassName('tr').length;
   let lastElem=document.getElementsByClassName('tr')[totalElem-1];
   $.get( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", function( data ) {
       $.each(data, function(i, item) {
           $(lastElem).after(placeHolder);
        });
     });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="item-form">
          <table class="add-items-table table table-hover ">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Quanty</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
                <th>Remove</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="item-row">
              <tr class="tr">
                <td style="width: 16.66%">
                  <input type="text" name="quanty" value="">
                </td>
                <td class="item-search-container">
                  <input class="item-input" id="item-input-0" type="search" name="item" value="">
                  <div class="item-search-results"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="quanty" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button class="remove-item-button btn-block btn-outline-danger" type="reset" name="remove">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <button class="add-item" onClick="addItem()">Add Another Item</button>
        </section>
```

Comment: It depends upon requirement and response from `REST API` not necessary.@kukumalu see the edits

Comment: But I don't have any problem to add new row. The problem I have is autocomplete result needs attach to respective `item-search-results` input field. Right now they don't

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are appending it to `$('.item-search-results')` that is a class and is returned as an array. When you run `.appendTo($('.item-search-results'))` it will append to the first item of the array.

You should use a more specific Id for each roll and append by Id.

I think @manikant 's idea of creating a template is great, but I would introduce a variable that you can change for each new row you create and give a different Id to each `.item-search-results` div. But you would have to send this to the websocket and receive it back to call the right Id to append.